# TypeVar in a nested type specification

Tags: python, mypy, type-hinting, python-typing

Let's say I have a type defined with `TypeVar`, like so:

```
T = TypeVar('T')
MyType = Union[list[T], tuple[T]]


def func(a: MyType[int]):
    pass
```

I also want to have an optional version of it:

```
MyTypeOpt = Optional[MyType]

def opt_func(a: MyTypeOpt[int] = None):
    pass
```

But this is not to mypy's liking and I'm getting an error: `Bad number of arguments for type alias, expected: 0, given: 1  [type-arg]`.

Is there a way to make it work without writing `Optional[MyType[...]]` every time?

Comment: `MyTypeOpt = Optional[MyType[T]]` should be the correct alias form. Why did you keep type var when aliasing first, but remove it in a second example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the type parameter for your generic type `MyType`. mypy is also complaining about that.

```py
from typing import Optional, Sequence, Tuple, Union

from typing_extensions import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')
MyType = Union[Sequence[T], Tuple[T]]
MyTypeOpt = Optional[MyType[T]]  # <---------


def func(a: MyType[int]) -> None:
    pass


def opt_func(a: MyTypeOpt[int] = None) -> None:
    pass


def opt_func2(a: Optional[MyType[int]] = None) -> None:
    pass
```